# java program to loop and output 2,5,7,10,12

Tags: java, loops

[Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry38F.png)

how to loop this without using array? I'm clearly confuse in this in java module I don't know the solution ;-; I'm new to java pls helppp mee

Comment: This exercise would clearly be related to a lesson that you have recently been given - so what have you learn recently ?  For example, have you covered Lists?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 25; i += 5)
    System.out.println(i / 2);
```

Or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    System.out.println(i * 5 / 2);
```

output:

```
2
5
7
10
12
```

Think for yourself why this produces the correct result.

Comment: did you do it one by one to find the correct solution to get the output?

Comment: I know that if odd-numbered and even-numbered increments of an integer sequence differ by 1, they are most likely other arithmetic sequences divided by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int outputNum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

            if (i % 2 == 0){
                outputNum += 2;
            }
            else {
                outputNum += 3;
            }
            System.out.print(outputNum + (i == 4 ? "" : " "));
        }
    }
}
```

This does exactly what you need. 
Explanation: 
In the loop if the `i` variable is even we add 2 to the output number (since you need to add 2 then 3 then 2...) and if `i` is uneven then we add three. At the end of the for loop we print the number without the newline using `System.out.print` and we separate them by a space if we aren't printing the last number using a ternary operator `(i == 4 ? "" : " ")` which returns a space if `i` is not equal to 4 and an empty string if it is, we do this to avoid having a space on the end of our output, so we get this `2 5 7 10 12` instead of this `2 5 7 10 12`